# Number of Days in a Month in java Date and LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

For startDate and endDate as follows how do I determin the period in Months and days (what is left of it):

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date start = format.parse("2016-11-09T02:00:00.000Z");
Date end = format.parse("2017-09-30T09:00:00.000Z");
```

As a result I want: 10 Months and 22 Days (end date in)

Comment: simple division problem `end.getTime () - start.endTime () / seconds in days`  **BUT** what is a month ? how many days?

Comment: If your environment is `Java 8`, then you can consider to use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) which is a much better datetime API for java. You can calculate days in between, hours in between, and yes even month in between using [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html)

Comment: @KarelG an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use `Java 8`, it is better to use `LocalDateTime` and `Period`:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-11-09T02:00:00.000Z");
ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-09-30T09:00:00.000Z");
System.out.println(Period.between(dateTime.toLocalDate(),end.toLocalDate()));
```

The result is `P10M21D` 10 Months and 21 Days

Comment: This can't give correct number of months, if difference between end and start is more than a year. You need to calculate months by 12*no of years+months. So don't use months directly.

Comment: @nagendra547, I am not quite sure if I have understood you. `Period` should show the correct amount of months. `System.out.println(Period.between(LocalDate.parse("1987-10-05"),LocalDate.now()));` 29 years and 11 months.

Comment: I think @nagendra547 told that *29 years and 11 months* should be returned as *359 months*. But the OP didn't specify what should be the result when the difference is >= 12 months, so both are correct IMO.

Comment: @Hugo, it is possible to get 359 months if we will use `ChronoUnit` instead of `Period` : `ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(LocalDate.parse("1987-10-05"),LocalDate.now())`

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine for you. This is done using [JODA Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). As you tagged this question also with jodatime so I am sure, you will have required packages for jodatime included in your project.

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date start = format.parse("2016-11-09T02:00:00.000Z");
Date end = format.parse("2017-09-30T09:00:00.000Z");

LocalDate a = LocalDate.fromDateFields(start);
LocalDate b = LocalDate.fromDateFields(end);
Period p = new Period(a, b);
System.out.println("Months:  "+((p.getYears() * 12) + p.getMonths()));
System.out.println("Days: "+(p.getWeeks()*7+ p.getDays()));
```

However, if you are using Java 8.0 or above, you can stick with solution suggested by @Anton.